# How to use C++ and Matlab Engine under Kdevelop with CMakeList

Tags: c++, matlab, cmake

I'm trying to use Matlab Engine with C++, but I have some problems.
This is my CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(test)
SET(PROJECT_PATH "/home/bruno/projects/Test")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
SET(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS ON)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)

include_directories (/home/bruno/MATLAB/R2017a/extern/include/)
link_directories(/home/bruno/MATLAB/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}  test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} -pthread )
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} libeng.so )
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} libmx.so )
```

When I try to execute test.cpp, I get

```
/home/bruno/projects/test/test.cpp:44: undefined reference to `matOpen'
```

and other undefined reference. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't linking to `libmat.so`:

```
target_link_libraries( ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} libmx libeng libmat )
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved!